# sql update query for ios

Tags: ios, sql

i want to update my database.database in to regno are not updating but other field updated.means that regno are constant.

```
  -(BOOL) updateData:(NSString*)name
            department:(NSString*)department year:(NSString*)year
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

            NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update into studentsDetail name=?, department=?, year=? where regno=? "];

            const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                return YES;
            }
            else{
                return  NO;
            }
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: I'm wondering how other field updated ? Because your query is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update query is wrong.
It should be like this.

```
UPDATE studentsDetail
SET name=?, department=?,year=?
WHERE regno=?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1,column2=value2 WHERE some_column=some_value;


NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update studentsDetail SET name='%@', department='%@', year='%@' where regno='%@'",@"name",@"dept",@"year",@"regno"];
```